# Python Classes using __init and __repr__ methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

Iam trying to create a class that should accept two arguments, x and y, and be represented by a string 'Point(x, y)' with appropriate values for x and y

```
class Point(object):


    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(%s,%s)"%(self.x, self.y)
```

Error:

```
Point(0,0) is not of type 'string'

Failed validating 'type' in schema['items']:
    {'type': 'string'}

On instance[0]:
    Point(0,0)
```

Comment: The error you have included is not from the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

"self.x" is the value of the instance of your class. So, if you set "self.x = 0", it means whenever you create an object for that class, the "x" value of that object will always be 0 instead of what you pass in the parameter.

"x" is the value of what you pass in the parameter.

> self.x = x
>
> self.y = y

Answer (score 0):

#### Code:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(%s,%s)"%(self.x, self.y)


thiss = MyClass(0, 0)
print(thiss.__repr__())

thiss = MyClass(20, 20)
print(thiss.__repr__())
```

#### Output:

```
daudn$ python3 point.py
Point(20,20)
daudn$ python3 point.py
Point(0,0)
```

When declaring your init function, you initialized self.x and self.y to always be 0. If you look at the code I've posted, whatever number you pass to the class will become the values or Point.